# How to configure SMS Multi-factor Auth in Firebase for a sole user with a specific role and pre-configure phone # rather than prompt user on signup?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication, multi-factor-authentication

I have a ReactJS app built on Firebase with user authentication based on a single factor - Email/Password provider - up and running.

I also have a special user in my Firebase Authentication database (this user has been assigned a unique role in the DB), and I would like to enable SMS Multi-factor Authentication in Firebase exclusively for this particular user.

I have already upgraded my Firebase Authentication to Identity Platform and SMS Multi-factor Authentication is now available in the Firebase console as an option.

I checked [the docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/multi-factor?hl=en&authuser=0&_gl=1*1sjtgfl*_ga*Njg1MjkxOTY0LjE2ODQ1MjE0Mzg.*_ga_CW55HF8NVT*MTY4ODY1NTY5OC4zNS4xLjE2ODg2NTY5NDguMC4wLjA.) and it looks like the third enrollment pattern would work for me in this case as I don't want to make it obvious to other users that SMS Multi-factor Authentication is available within the app, for I only require a single user to ever use the multi-factor method:

> Provide the ability to add a second factor from the user's account or profile management page, instead of the sign up screen. This minimizes
> friction during the registration process, while still making
> multi-factor authentication available for security-sensitive users.

In the meantime, I don't have any "*user's account*" or "*profile management*" pages in my app and I do not intend to create them. I only need to setup the phone number for this particular user in the DB once and prompt this phone number for SMS codes anytime this particular user signs in the app.

Is there a way to bypass the "Enrolling a second factor" step of the docs (as I only need to enroll a specific user once and that's it) and set up the phone number for a specific user manually in the Firebase DB, going straight to the "Signing users in with a second factor" step of the docs after the user's phone number is pre-configured?

The docs give a pretty straightforward way to 1) Enable multi-factor authentication; 2) Choose an enrollment pattern; 3) Set up the reCAPTCHA verifier; 4) Enroll user with a second factor; 5) Sign user in with a second factor, but I couldn't find an option to omit step 4 above and setup the second factor for a specific user manually through the console whereas I do not want any other user in my app to be able to setup the second factor by themselves.

Thanks in advance!